# WP7 SQL Server CE How to Update

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

I'm updating my Windows Phone App to Mango and starting to use SQL Server CE. I can insert and select data but am struggling to understand how to update data.

Most of the examples are basic tutorials and only show inserting and retrieving data not updating. I believe I need to attach a class I have retrieved to the data context but that is as far as I have got.

Please can someone point me to an online tutorial showing how to do this. Or some example code would be great.

Thanks.

*UPDATE*

Basic updating looks fairly simple - query the database, update the object, call SubmitChanges.

My scenario is a little more complicated.

I have a page showing a list of jobs. A job (JobDetail) is selected and another page is used to edit the details. The job is written to a cache (another table JobCache) while the job is edited. If the user cancels the edit the cache is deleted. If the user saves the edit the JobCache object is pulled from the cache, converted to an object of type JobDetail and now I want to update the database with the new JobDetail object.I don't think I can just call SubmitChanges as the object was not generated from a query. I believe I need to somehow use Attach to do this. The question is how?

Comment: The context should have an attach method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not get the original JobDetail object, update the changed properties from the cahced object and call SubmitChanges ?

Comment: This was the solution I went with. I also had to code for a new job (object not already in database).